# Will one pic programmer program all pic chips?

Tags: pic, integrated-circuit, programmer

If yes which one and where could i buy it and is there an inexpensive programmer for the chips?

Comment: program in circuit and dont worry about such things

Comment: do you know a website that shows how to do that @PlasmaHH

Comment: Assuming you mean a Microchip PIC, some programmers will, others wont. Generally though the programmers will list which they support, so pick one which has the ones you will likely use, or use one of the official tools like the PICKit which support most. If by 'pic' you mean a programmable integrated circuit in general, the no, each manufacturer will likely use different programming methods.

Comment: sorry for not making it clear and yes i did mean the microchip pic

Comment: As you may have sussed out from the answers in-circuit programmers (what you asked about) will not necessarily support debugging (what you probably would like to have), so you ought to consider that. Programming out-of-circuit (requiring a socket to fit the chip) is another function again.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no single programmer that will program all PICs.

If you go to the in the installation directory for MPLABX (on my machine it is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLABX\docs"), there should be a file called DeviceSupport.htm.  It lists all of the PICs supported by each debugger, along with the associated compilers too.  Here is the beginning of it:

[image]

*Most* devices are supported by the PICkit3 and ICD 3.

You can also get the same information for a single PIC by opening up the Project Properties dialog in MPLABX and selecting a part number.  In the middle of the dialog, it will show which debuggers are supported.  For example, for the 32-bit PIC32MX795F512L, all the debuggers are supported except for PICkit2 (an older device) with a red dot next to the name.

[image]